# Codeigniter: website have too many redirects

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have developed a webportal in codeigniter framework,but when i try to host in a shared hosting server i will get this error.

> wwww.abc.com redirected you too many times. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I don't know what was the problem

Here is my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*[NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) $1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

**UPDATE**
I have contacted with hosting support team ,they said that it was a mode security error. Here the log about it.

> ModSecurity: Access denied with redirection to
>   http://spotmyticket.com/ using status 302 (phase 4). Pattern match
>   "^5\\d{2}$" at RESPONSE_STATUS. [file
>   "/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec_vendor_configs/OWASP/rules/RESPONSE-50-DATA-LEAKAGES.conf"]
>   [line "14"] [id "970901"] [rev "3"] [msg "The Application Returned a
>   500-Level Status Code"] [data "Matched Data: 500 found within
>   RESPONSE_STATUS: 500"] [severity "ERROR"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.0.0"]
>   [maturity "9"] [accuracy "9"] [tag "Host: spotmyticket.com"] [tag
>   "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"]
>   [tag "attack-information disclosure"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-13"] [tag
>   "OWASP_TOP_10/A6"] [tag "PCI/6.5.6"] [hostname "spotmyticket.com"]
>   [uri "/index.php"] [unique_id "VxpEf2f3YKwABUKkyP4AAABb"]

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on                       
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
 
DirectoryIndex index.php
 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

Comment: I can't  get your answer