# .htaccess file codeigniter:site can't be reached

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am work with a codeigniter project,when i move my code to the live server it can't be reached.
My project folder name is `agentportal` and i moved the entire file from  this to `public_html` folder on my live server.
But the site can't reached  i have contacted with the hosting support team, they said that its `mode security issue`.

Here is the log from server.

> [error] [client 182.75.75.90] ModSecurity: Access denied with
>   redirection to http://spotmyticket.com/ using status 302 (phase 4).
>   Pattern match "^5\\d{2}$" at RESPONSE_STATUS. [file
>   "/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec_vendor_configs/OWASP/rules/RESPONSE-50-DATA-LEAKAGES.conf"]
>   [line "14"] [id "970901"] [rev "3"] [msg "The Application Returned a
>   500-Level Status Code"] [data "Matched Data: 500 found within
>   RESPONSE_STATUS: 500"] [severity "ERROR"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.0.0"]
>   [maturity "9"] [accuracy "9"] [tag "Host: spotmyticket.com"] [tag
>   "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"]
>   [tag "attack-information disclosure"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-13"] [tag
>   "OWASP_TOP_10/A6"] [tag "PCI/6.5.6"] [hostname "spotmyticket.com"]
>   [uri "/index.php"] [unique_id "VxsfjGf3YKwACih0ZhoAAABJ"]

Everything works fine in local machine

Here is my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*[NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) $1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

When i access the site i will the following error message

> This site can’t be reached
>
> abc.com refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Server support guy said its the **problem with `.htaccess` file.**
What's wrong with my `.htaccess` file?
please help:(

Comment: You said it yourself that it was a `ModSecurity` issue. disable that mod temporarily and see if you can access the site.

Comment: I can't disable it bcz its shared hosting server

Comment: ModSecurity is only blocking because your application returned an 500 error status. This is a security projection to prevent the whole stack trace being returned to client. Questions: 1) What caused this 500 status? 2) Are there any other errors before this that might explain why the error was returned?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter: website have too many redirects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36801180/codeigniter-website-have-too-many-redirects)